# php curl multipart/form-data can't proccess

Tags: php, curl

I have simple array;

```
 [specifics] => Array
        (
            [0] => RT
            [1] => 2S
        )
```

Then i create it to query;

```
http_build_query($array);

specifics%5B0%5D=RT&specifics%5B1%5D=2S
```

Both doesn't work.

```
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, $info2['url']);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
```

This is the code i'm using.

Comment: So you're a software developer, and one of your users comes to you and says: "Your program doesn't work!" - What would you tell them?

Comment: Hi there user969724, I see that you're somewhat new to StackOverflow. This question cannot be answered in it's current state because it doesn't provide us with necessary information. Namely. What error you're getting. Remember, the quality of answer depends on how well you ask the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.This is what i get from the headers of the page.

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2012 00:32:05 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 3542
nnCoection: close
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Some remote server does not recognize the "%5B0%5D" in the query

```
specifics%5B0%5D=RT&specifics%5B1%5D=2S
```

Try the following

```
http_build_query($array, '', '&');
```

Comment: Be careful of the url encoding with http_build_query for using with curl. You can test curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query) with a sample url firstly